# How to get the last document from a VueFire query

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

Getting frustrated to solve this since I am no JS expert.

I am using Firestore as a database and VuexFire to bind the data to VueX state, like so.

```html
 getLeads: firestoreAction(async ({
        bindFirestoreRef
    }) => {
        // return the promise returned by `bindFirestoreRef`
        return bindFirestoreRef('leads', db.collection('leads').orderBy('updated.date', 'desc').limit(30))
    }),
```

It gets the first 30 results and then i want to implement an infinite scroll feature to run a function every time the scroll reaches the bottom and fetch more data and bind to the same state. In Firestore pagination require passing a query cursor of the last fetched document as a reference

Below from firebase document, with vanilla JS

```html
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

since I use VuexFire to bind the data to state, I dont see an option to get the snapshot of the last document fetched by VuexFire (lastVisible from the above code), in order to pass it to the next query.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say I have a collection of Customer records and i am displaying the first 5 ordered by last updated.

The query is

```
getLeads: firestoreAction(({ commit, bindFirestoreRef
}) => {
    bindFirestoreRef('Leads', db.collection('leads')
   .orderBy('updated.date', 'desc').limit(5)).then(documents => {
        commit('POPULATE_TESTLEADS', documents);
        commit('LAST_DOC', documents[documents.length - 1]);
    });

}),
```

I am saving both the results and the lastdoc in the state, looping and showing the names, like so:

```
Nakheel
Emaar Group
Yapi Kredi Inc
Cairo Amman Bank
Arab Jordan Investment Bank LLC
```

I then call again with the last doc as query cursor and expect the next 5 docs to return from firebase, like so

```
moreLeadLeads: firestoreAction(({ state, bindFirestoreRef
}) => {
    bindFirestoreRef('testLeads', db.collection('leads')
    .orderBy('updated.date', 'desc')
   .startAfter(state.lastDoc).limit(5))
}),
```

But I get the same 5 results as above from firestore. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 3):

Internally VueFire and VuexFire use a `serializer` function that maps each Document  returned by RTDB or Firestore into the data objects that are bound to the final component or Vuex store state.

The default `serializer` is implemented by the function [createSnapshot](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/packages/@posva/vuefire-core/src/firestore/utils.ts#L10) that is part of the vuefire-core library:

```js
/**
 * @param {firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot} doc
 * @return {DocumentData}
 */
export function createSnapshot (doc) {
  // defaults everything to false, so no need to set
  return Object.defineProperty(doc.data(), 'id', {
    value: doc.id
  })
}
```

As you can see it returns only `doc.data()` (with `id` added) and discards the `doc` object. However when implementing Firestore pagination via `query.startAfter(doc)` we need the original `doc` object. The good news is that VueFire and VuexFire APIs allow us to replace the `serializer` with our own that can preserve the doc object like so:

```js
const serialize = (doc: firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
  const data = doc.data();
  Object.defineProperty(data, 'id', { value: doc.id });
  Object.defineProperty(data, '_doc', { value: doc });
  return data;
}
```

We can configure our new VuexFire serializer either globally via [plugin options](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#options-serialize) or per binding via [binding options](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuexfire.html#options).

// Globally defined
Vue.use(firestorePlugin, { serialize });

// OR per binding
bindFirebaseRef('todos', db.ref('todos'), { serialize } )

For VuexFire, we can now get access to the first document as `state.todos[0]._doc` or last document `state.todos[state.todos.length-1]._doc` and use them to implement pagination queries for collections or "get next" & "get previous" queries that bind single documents (essential when your base query has multi-field sorting).

NOTE: Because `_doc` and `id` are non-enumerable properties, they won't appear on component or store objects in [Vue DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en).

Comment: I am having the same issue. This almost got me there but I'm still unclear on how to get the paginated query results to bind to the original state data. I was not able to add a comment before so I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639778/paginating-firestore-data-when-using-vuex-and-appending-new-data-to-the-state

Comment: I've added some possible solutions for extending this to implement pagination. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650214/365261

Answer (score 1):

From the VueFire documentation on [binding data and using it](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding), the `$bind` method (which I assume your `bindFirestoreRef` wraps) returns a promise with the result (as well as binding it to `this`). From that documentation:

> ```
> this.$bind('documents', documents.where('creator', '==', this.id)).then(documents => {
>   // documents will point to the same property declared in data:
>   // this.documents === documents
> })
> ```

So you should be able to do the same, and then get the document from the array with something like:

```
bindFirestoreRef('leads', db.collection('leads').orderBy('updated.date', 'desc').limit(30)).then(documents => {
  this.lastDoc = documents[documents.length - 1];
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But it deoesnt seem to work. Actually passing last document data to firestore cant be used as a query cursor. I should be passing a document reference, which is the parent of the document $bind returns :(

Comment: Can you show me the docs of the method that takes a document reference to initialize a cursor? In the clients that I regularly work with ([JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html#startat), ReactNative, [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAt(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)), Swift, Flutter) it's a document *snapshot* as that contains the actual data that the cursor needs.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Its under Paginate a Query section

Comment: document snapshot  is what the cursor needs, however, as in my original question, documents from $bind in VuexFire retunrs the actual data of the document and not the document snapshot.

Comment: You can also pass an array of values, instead of a document snapshot.

Comment: I have no clue why its not working. Lemme see if i can put up some code somewhere for you to refer.